# Neo4j-ogm query path

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In my Java code I have a query to match the shortest path from root to a leaf in my tree.

```
Strinq query = "Match path = (p:Root)-[*1..100]-(m:Leaf) "
    + "WITH p,m,path ORDER BY length(path) LIMIT 1 RETURN path";
```

However, when I try to query this as follows

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("incyan.Data.Neo4j.Models");
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession("http://localhost:7474");
Object o = session(query, new HashMap<String,Object>());
```

`o` contains an `ArrayList` of `LinkedHashMap`s instead of mapped objects.

I cannot even determine the labels of the path elements and the start and end nodes of the relations.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current neo4j-ogm release does not map query results to domain entities. Returning a path will only give you the properties of nodes and relationships in that path (in order, so you can infer the relationship start/end). ID's aren't returned by the Neo4j REST api currently used by the OGM for this particular operation and that's why they are missing. You may instead have to extract the ID's and return them as part of your query.

Mapping individual query result columns to entities will be available in a Neo4j-OGM 2.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Java bit, but if you use the [`shortestPath`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#query-shortest-path) function (keyword?) your query should be more efficient:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((p:Root)-[*1..100]-(m:Leaf))
RETURN path
```

Also, I don't know what your data model is like, but I would expect the labels on the nodes of your tree (I'm assuming it's a tree) to all be the same.  You can tell if a node is a root or a leaf using Cypher:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((root:Element)-[*1..100]-(leaf:Element))
WHERE NOT((root)-[:HAS_PARENT]->()) AND NOT(()-[:HAS_PARENT]->(leaf))
RETURN path
```

Comment: >>but if you use the shortestPath function...

Thanx a lot. Will modify my query.

>>> I don't know what your data model is like, but I would expect the labels on the nodes of your tree...

Nope. My tree has a single root element which is marked with label 'Root'. All other nodes have labels either 'Leaf' or 'BranchBase'. 

If I execute the query in the neo4j web gui, it returns the correct path. My problem is related to the java's neo4j-ogm library. It does not map the returned objects to my java entities defined as described here:
http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/

Comment: Instead, session.query() returns an `ArrayList` of `LinkedHashMap`s.

Comment: Ah, fair enough then.  I'll let somebody else answer the java OGM question ;)  Also, in case you don't know, nodes in Neo4j can have multiple labels, so if you want to label some nodes as `Root` / `Leaf`, you can also still have another label which encompasses all of them for different querying situation.